# Better solution for loading data onto a map

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, maps, bing-maps

I'd like to ask if anyone knows a good solution to my problem.
I have a Rails project with a Bing map, where I need to load about 20000 pushpins.

The problem that I have is the speed of my data load. I've tried to optimize the load time by only including required fields for records (id, latitude, longitude). It made some difference but still was not a good load time.

Next thing that I've done - started loading records in batches (a couple hundred at a time). As a result, pushpins started showing up almost instantly, but again, it took a really long time to fully load the data set.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions about a better way to load the data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several solutions to achieve what you want to do but the main question would be, do you really need to display the 20k pushpins onto the map control and display them all at once? I'm pretty sure it will lack of readibility and adding to performance cost, you might consider dynamicaly restrict the number of elements that will be displayed and load only those who can really be seen.

**1: Client-side clustering**

Using your own implementation or the Bing Maps Module available here: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Client%20Side%20Clustering, you can create cluster to ease the data manipulation and rendering of the pushpins.

**2: Dynamicaly load (Server-side clipping and clustering)**

Each time you fire 'onviewchanged', you can make an AJAX call to refresh the information and clear the previously added pin. Also, if you are a zoom level or in a specific area where you have to display every pushpin, you can create cluster of pushpins so you will display only one pushpin that says 'there are 12 pins in here'. I'm sure you get the point.

**3: Composing dynamic tile on server-side or on client-side**

If you need to display everything, the latest solution would be to draw things on dynamical tiles on server-side or on client-side depending on your use case, see: http://www.web-maps.com/gisblog/?p=1605

Comment: Thank you! Those suggestions are exactly what I've been looking for. I've been doing the client side clustering, but that required the data set to be loaded. I will definitely consider loading only data that should be visible initially and reload it any time user interacts with a map. Thanks again!